# number prob in ts and js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have created  a form using react and the file is of .tsx extension.

Answer (score 1):

> The JavaScript Number type is a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value, like double in Java or C#.

Checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number for more information

And check out this previous stack overflow answer on how to avoid this problem [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)